# NonUniqueObjectException: when updating an entity with hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

i have three entities:

-**Authority** , **Permission** , **PermissionCategory**

-**Desc:** authority can contain many permissions, and permission can be in many authorities, and permissionCategory can contain many permissions.

**1- Authority >**  **Many To Many** With **Permission**

```
class Authority{

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinTable(name = "authority_permission", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "authority_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "permission_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
        private Set<Permission> permissions = new HashSet<Permission>(0);

    }
```

**2- PermissionCategory >**  **One To Many** With **Permission**

```
class PermissionCategory{

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinTable(name = "perm_cat_map", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "perm_cat_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "permission_id") })
        private Set<Permission> permissions = new HashSet<Permission>(0);

       }
```

**3- Permission >**  **Many To One** With **PermissionCategory**

```
class Permission{

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private PermissionCategory permissionCategory;

}
```

**Case 1:** Adding a new role

- When adding a new role, user chooses already existing permissions, so i need to insert in authority and in join table (Authority_Permission)

so i make it as follows:

```
Set<Permission> permissions=new HashSet<Permission>;
Permission permission=permissionDao.getPermissionById(1); 
permissions.add(permission);   
authority.setPermissions(permissions);
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().merge(authority); // it works only with merge
```

this case works fine.

**Case 2:** Deleteing a role

when deleting a role, role is deleted and associated role permissions, but also the permissions themselves are getting deleted which i don't want too, please advise what cascade type should i use then, i want role and permissions only to be deleted.

**Case 3:** Updating a role

- User may change the role properties, and the associated permissions, so what's needed is to updated the authority object and update the associated permissions, if a permission was removed then remove it and if a permission was added to add it.

so i made it as follows:

```
    Set<Permission> permissions=new HashSet<Permission>;
    Permission permission=permissionDao.getPermissionById(1); 
    permissions.add(permission);   
    authority.setPermissions(permissions);
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(authority);
```

problem is when trying to update a role as mentioned above, i am getting exception:

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [com.myapp.domain.Permission#3]; nested exception is org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [com.myapp.domain.Permission#3]
javax.faces.FacesException: #{authority.addOrUpdateAuthority}: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [com.myapp.domain.Permission#3]; nested exception is org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [com.myapp.domain.Permission#3]
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:368)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:471)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:329)
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:368)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:964)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [com.myapp.domain.Permission#3]; nested exception is org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [com.myapp.domain.Permission#3]
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 87 more
Caused by: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [com.myapp.domain.Permission#3]; nested exception is org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [com.myapp.domain.Permission#3]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:679)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:793)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:664)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:393)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy30.updateAuthority(Unknown Source)
    at com.myapp.beans.AuthorityBean.addOrUpdateAuthority(AuthorityBean.java:110)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:262)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    ... 88 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [com.myapp.domain.Permission#3]
    at org.hibernate.engine.StatefulPersistenceContext.checkUniqueness(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:637)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:305)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:677)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:669)
    at org.hibernate.engine.CascadingAction$5.cascade(CascadingAction.java:252)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:392)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:335)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:362)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.engine.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.cascadeOnFlush(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.prepareEntityFlushes(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1206)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:375)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:137)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:656)
    ... 104 more
```

I am using **Hibernate 3.5.1-Final**
please advise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

well it works fine after i make **merging** then **save** or **update**, as follows:

**1- Save Role: (insert new role object, insert into join table Authority_Permission)**

```
authority = (Authority) getCurrentSession().merge(authority);
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(authority);
```

**2- Update Role (update role object, update join table Authority_Permission> delete/insert):**

```
authority = (Authority) getCurrentSession().merge(authority);
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(authority);
```

**3- Delete Role: (delete role object, delete from join table Authority_Permission)**

it works fine after removing `cascade = CascadeType.ALL`

```
class Authority{

    @ManyToMany
        @JoinTable(name = "authority_permission", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "authority_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "permission_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
        private Set<Permission> permissions = new HashSet<Permission>(0);
```

and using only:

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(authority);
```

but i need some experienced explanation here from anyone, why i need merging then save or update, and if that solution is the best, just found it in a blog.

Comment: Your solution helped me overcome the same issue I had with Hibernate. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You have a `Permission` with `id` 3 in your session and you try to add different `Permission` with the same id to the session. Hibernate guarantees there is never ever an entity represented twice in a session, so it throws the exception

This probably happens because you load some objects using the session (through your DAOs). These are attached to the session, i.e. they are IN the session.

You have other objects that come from outside the session. Originally probably from a different session (maybe the last request) although this session might be closed by now. Maybe you create them directly using `new`. The culprit is probably the `authority` object with referenced permissions.

When you `save`/`update` the `authority` it tries to drag the referenced permissions into the session and you get the exception.

The merge gives you the object for an entity that is already in the session (and sets all fields according to the new state, possibly cascading to referenced objects, depending on the configuration). Therefore you have only one object per entity and everybody (or at least Hibernate) is happy

Comment: thanks for good explanation, i updated my question about delete role case, can you please advise me.